# Actionscript3 clearInterval is not working on TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN

Tags: actionscript-3

I have called a `setInterval` on `TouchEvent.TOUCH_END` and I want to clear it when ever screen is touched.

Here is my code:

```
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.*;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);

function onTouchBegin(evt:TouchEvent)
{
    clearInterval(MovieClip(root).myInterval);
}

function onTouchEnd(evt:TouchEvent)
{
    MovieClip(root).myInterval = setInterval(showTimer,1000);
}

function showTimer()
{
    trace("interval working");
}
```

Comment: Any additional details (like why your code doesn't work) would be helpful.

Comment: How would you know it's not working? You set it when the touch ends so it should never stops tracing and calling showTimer. For that reason clearing the interval should only have an effect if you touch and hold the finger down.

Comment: Actually this is a very simple application. There will be a windows touch based gesture system where a fullscreen video will be running. If user touch it and swap it left, the video will go backward and swapping right will take video forward. The swap will back or forward video real-time, not jumpy. I am not sure if it needs touch event or click? I will appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your provided code doesn't really explain everything so there will be a fair bit of speculation in this answer:

**Possiblity No. 1:**

Your way of casting `root` to `MovieClip` is not working. Try changing to following:

```
function onTouchBegin(evt:TouchEvent)
{
     var intervalRef:int = (root as MovieClip).myInterval;
     clearInterval(intervalRef);
}
```

**Possiblity No. 2:**

It seems that your code is written in a frame. And although if you define something in a previous frame it should work, but if you have the code on a different (lower) layer on the same keyframe it could define the variable later and your `MovieClip(root).myInterval` variable is `undefined` or `null` is the value is not defined. So check if your variable even exists:

```
function onTouchBegin(evt:TouchEvent)
{
    trace(MovieClip(root) == null); // see if the root is defined
    trace(MovieClip(root).myInterval); // see if the myInterval is defined
}
```

**Possiblity No. 3:**

You're cycling through frames. When I had 2 frames: one blank and one with your code, the code didn't work properly. Tested in Flash CC.

**Possibility No. 4:**

You have a run-time error somewhere else and your whole frame's code is not being executed. Do you use the debug version of Flash Player?

**Possible solution for less headache:**

Use a `Timer`. It's easy to control, easy to manage and dispose of. I've edited your code to work with Timer and tested. Feel free to use it for your project.

```
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

var timer:Timer = (timer == null) ? new Timer(1000) : timer;
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onTouchBegin); // you can change back to TouchEvent, but since you're using TOUCH_POINT it's pointless so I'd just use MouseEvent
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onTouchEnd);

function onTouchBegin(evt:Event)
{
    timer.stop();
}

function onTouchEnd(evt:Event)
{
    timer.start();
}

function showTimer()
{
    trace("interval working");
}

function onTick(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    showTimer();
}
```

*I do want to note that your code works if I just copy-paste it in a single frame Flash file. But still, it's encouraged by Adobe to use Timer instead.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I really really appreciate. The timer code seems the best practice.

I am new on as3 and touch things.. Could you please let me know if mouse events works in touch gesture?

Thanks again

Comment: @MokarramKhan Mouse gestures are different from touch input. If you don't have gestures such as: swipe, pitch, rotate etc. then you're using touch points and you can use MouseEvent for that. I usually use MouseEvent instead of TouchEvent if I don't use gestures and I want my app to work for both browser-Flash and mobile Flash (AIR).

Comment: Hello @creative Magic. Thanks for your reply. Actually this is a very simple application. There will be a windows touch based gesture system where a fullscreen video will be running. If user touch it and swap it left, the video will go backward and swapping right will take video forward. The swap will back or forward video real-time, not jumpy. I am not sure if it needs touch event or click? I will appreciate your reply. Thanks

Comment: If you plan to use gesture input (swipe, rotate, pinch etc.) or you want to use more than one touch (double finger tap, pinch, etc.) you'll need to use GESTURE. You can use NONE or TOUCH_POINT for single finger touches and it will be interpreted as a mouse event. It's not that one is better than the other, it's just that you need to choose what you plan to use it for ;)